# Learning Laplace by doing, but getting unexpected result in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fft

I'm trying to learn more about the Laplace transform, so I've tried to implement the forward and inverse (Mellin's inverse formula) transforms in code (approximated using the trapezium rule). I would expect to get roughly the same information back out when doing the forward and inverse one after the other. However, the output values appear to have nothing to do with the input data.

**CODE:**

```
# Dependencies:
from math import ceil
from cmath import *
import numpy as np


# Constants
j = complex(0, 1)
e = exp(1).real


# Default Values
sigma_default = 0  # Real component. When 0, the result is the Fourier transform


# Forward Transform - Time Domain to Laplace Domain
def Laplace(data, is_inverse, sigma=sigma_default, frequency_stamps=None, time_stamps=None):
    # Resolve empty data scenario
    data = np.asarray(data)
    if data.size <= 1:
        return data

    # Add time data if missing
    if time_stamps is None:
        if is_inverse is False:
            time_stamps = np.arange(0, data.size)
        else:
            time_stamps = np.arange(0, data.size * 2)
    else:
        time_stamps = np.asarray(time_stamps).real
        if time_stamps.size is not data.size:
            time_stamps = np.arange(0, data.size)

    # Add frequency stamps if missing
    if frequency_stamps is None:
        if is_inverse is False:
            frequency_stamps = np.asarray(np.arange(0, ceil(data.size / 2))).real * 2 * pi  # Added forgotten constant
        else:
            frequency_stamps = np.asarray(np.arange(0, ceil(data.size))).real * 2 * pi  # Added forgotten constant
    else:
        frequency_stamps = np.asarray(frequency_stamps).real
    frequency_stamps = sigma + frequency_stamps * j

    # Create the vector of powers exp(1) is raised to. Also create the delta times / frequencies
    if is_inverse is False:
        power = -Get_Powers(time_stamps, frequency_stamps)
        delta = np.diff(time_stamps)
    else:
        power = Get_Powers(frequency_stamps, time_stamps)
        delta = np.diff(frequency_stamps)
    delta = np.concatenate([[np.average(delta)], delta])  # Ensure a start value is present

    # Perform a numerical approximation of the Laplace transform
    laplace = data * np.power(e, power) * delta

    # Trapezium rule => average 1st and last wrt zero
    laplace = laplace.transpose()  # Fixed bug in trapezium rule implementation
    laplace[[0, -1]] *= 0.5
    laplace = laplace.transpose()
    laplace = np.sum(laplace, 1)  # Integrate

    # If inverse function, then normalise and ensure the result is real
    if is_inverse is True:
        laplace *= 1 / (2 * pi * j)  # Scale
        laplace = laplace.real  # Ensure time series is real only

    # Return the result
    return laplace


# Used to derive the vector of powers exp(1) is to be raised to
def Get_Powers(values1, values2):
    # For forward Laplace, 1 = time, 2 = frequency
    # For inverse Laplace, 1 = frequency, 2 = time
    power = np.ones([values1.size, values2.size])
    power = (power * values2).transpose() * values1
    return power


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    a = np.arange(0, 10)
    b = Laplace(a, False)
    c = Laplace(b, True)
    print(np.asarray(a))
    print(c)
```

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[162. 162. 162. 162. 162. 162. 162. 162. 162. 162.]
```

Any ideas where I've gone awry?

**EDIT 1: Added Laplace functions:**

Forwards transform: [image: Laplace Forwards]

Inverse transform: [image: Laplace Inverse]

Definition of `s`: [image: Define S]

Where `omega` is represented as `frequency_stamps` in my code. When `sigma = 0` the system becomes the Fourier transform.

**EDIT 2: Fixed two bugs. Problem still persists**

Comment: Check the algorithm implementation.

Comment: @LazyCoder I've already tried that but I'm not seeing where its fallen over. I wouldn't have posted a question if I'd found it already =p

Comment: Can you include algorithm template/pseudocode for laplace inverse.

Comment: @LazyCoder Updated with the equations shown. Apologies it took so long, I'm still learning how to do that properly in stack overflow.

Comment: You’re implementing integrals over the infinite domain as a finite sum, and expecting the same results. That is simply not possible.

Comment: @CrisLuengo It is assumed that the regions not of interest are held at 0, so integral should still be the same no?

Comment: You cannot make that assumption for the Laplace transformed signal. Look at how you go from the Fourier Transform to the Discrete Fourier Transform. That is not a trivial step. You can’t just sample your signal and your transform at arbitrary locations and expect it to work. Instead, look into the [z-transform](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the two bug fixes made in the original question, there were a further 3 bugs left that I identified via Cris Luengo's suggestion to look into the conversion from the [Fourier Transform into the Discrete Fourier Transform](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/mdft/DFT_Derived.html). A summary of all bug fixes is below:

1. Fixed a bug in how I implemented the trapezium rule.
2. Scaled the `frequency_stamps` by `2*pi` to reflect the underlying circular nature of the Laplace data.
3. Rescaled the `frequency_stamps` again such that they only travel around a circle once (aka. the data is in the range `0 -> 2*pi`).
4. Fixed a mistake where I'd assumed that there only needed to be half as many frequency points than time points. That's wrong. There should be an equal amount of both.
5. Allowed the passing of initial and final time series points for the inverse transform as the data otherwise gets corrupted.

**Updated Code:**

```
# Dependencies:
from cmath import *
import numpy as np


# Constants
j = complex(0, 1)
e = exp(1).real


# Default Values
sigma_default = 0.0  # Real component. When 0, the result is the Fourier transform
ends_default = np.asarray([0, 0])


# Forward Transform - Time Domain to Laplace Domain
def Laplace(data, is_inverse, sigma=sigma_default, frequency_stamps=None, time_stamps=None, ends=ends_default):
    # Resolve empty data scenario
    data = np.asarray(data)
    if data.size <= 1:
        return data

    # Add time data if missing
    if time_stamps is None:
        time_stamps = np.arange(0, data.size)  # Size doesn't change between forward and inverse
    else:
        time_stamps = np.asarray(time_stamps).real
        if time_stamps.size is not data.size:
            time_stamps = np.arange(0, data.size)

    # Add frequency stamps if missing
    if frequency_stamps is None:
        frequency_stamps = np.asarray(np.arange(0.0, data.size)).real  # Size doesn't change between forward and inverse
        frequency_stamps *= 2 * pi / np.max(frequency_stamps)  # Restrict the integral range to 0 -> 2pi
    else:
        frequency_stamps = np.asarray(frequency_stamps).real
    frequency_stamps = sigma + frequency_stamps * j

    # Create the vector of powers exp(1) is raised to. Also create the delta times / frequencies
    if is_inverse is False:
        power = -Get_Powers(time_stamps, frequency_stamps)
        delta = np.diff(time_stamps)
    else:
        power = Get_Powers(frequency_stamps, time_stamps)
        delta = np.diff(frequency_stamps)
    delta = np.concatenate([[np.average(delta)], delta])  # Ensure a start value is present

    # Perform a numerical approximation of the Laplace transform
    laplace = data * np.power(e, power) * delta
    laplace = laplace.transpose()
    laplace[[0, -1]] *= 0.5  # Trapezium rule => average 1st and last wrt zero
    laplace = laplace.transpose()
    laplace = np.sum(laplace, 1)  # Integrate

    # If inverse function, then normalise and ensure the result is real
    if is_inverse is True:
        laplace *= 1 / (2 * pi * j)  # Scale
        laplace = laplace.real  # Ensure time series is real only

        # Correct for edge cases
        laplace[0] = ends[0]
        laplace[-1] = ends[-1]

    # Return the result
    return laplace


# Used to derive the vector of powers exp(1) is to be raised to
def Get_Powers(values1, values2):
    # For forward Laplace, 1 = time, 2 = frequency
    # For inverse Laplace, 1 = frequency, 2 = time
    power = np.ones([values1.size, values2.size])
    power = (power * values2).transpose() * values1
    return power


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = np.arange(3, 13)
    b = Laplace(a, False, sigma=0.5)
    c = Laplace(b, True, sigma=0.5, ends=np.asarray([3, 12]))
    print(np.asarray(a))
    print(c)
```

**Output**

```
[ 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12]
[ 3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10. 11. 12.]
```

Thanks for the assist!